# How can you implement an If statement in a SQLite trigger?

Tags: sql, linq, sqlite

We have a self-referencing relationship defined in our SQLite database as such...

```
Create Table Categories{
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(length(Text) > 0),
    ParentId INTEGER References Categories(Id),
    IsSelected BOOL
};
```

We're trying to set a trigger up on the IsSelected field to automatically propagate the values up the hierarchy.

When setting the value to True, it's easy. We simply set the trigger to set its parent to True, which in turn does the same for its parent, walking up the hierarchy until it gets to the root.

When we're setting it to False however, that logic doesn't apply because there could be another sibling of the record being changed that is still true, so its parent is still true.

So how do I do the following in a trigger? Note, this is obviously a nonsensical hybrid of SQL, C# and LINQ, but it illustrates what I'm trying to do.

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_Categories_IsSelectedChanged
UPDATE OF IsSelected ON Categories
BEGIN
    if(new.IsSelected)
        Update Categories Set IsSelected = True Where Id = old.ParentId;
    else
    {
        void isSiblingSelected = Categories
            .Where(c => c.ParentId = old.ParentId)
            .Any(c => c.IsSelected);

        UPDATE Categories 
        SET IsSelected = isSiblingSelected
        WHERE Id = old.ParentId;
    }
END
```

Now technically the 'Else' clause works in both cases. The If was more a short-circuit, but perhaps I could do something like this...

```
Update Categories
SET IsSelected = (
    SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Categories
    WHERE IsSelected = True 
    AND ParentId = old.ParentId
    LIMIT 1))
Where ID = old.ParentId;
```

...but that's just a guess. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CASE is not a statement; you could use it only inside an expression.

However, triggers have a [WHEN clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) which takes an arbitrary SQL expression:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_Categories_IsSelectedChanged_true
AFTER UPDATE OF IsSelected ON Categories
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN new.IsSelected
BEGIN
    UPDATE Categories
    SET IsSelected = 1
    WHERE Id = old.ParentId;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER T_Categories_IsSelectedChanged_false
AFTER UPDATE OF IsSelected ON Categories
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NOT new.IsSelected
BEGIN
    UPDATE Categories 
    SET IsSelected = (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(IsSelected), 0)
                      FROM Categories
                      WHERE ParentId = old.ParentId)
    WHERE Id = old.ParentId;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can refer http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case.

i am not sure but you code might be like,

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_Categories_IsSelectedChanged
UPDATE OF IsSelected ON Categories
BEGIN
case when new.isSelected then
    Update Categories Set IsSelected = True Where Id = old.ParentId;
else
    Update Categories Set IsSelected = Categories
        .Where(c => c.ParentId = old.ParentId)
        .Any(c => c.IsSelected);
END
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Case statement, but as I said, my code is not actually SQL. It's LINQ just to show the logic.  But I'll check out the Case statement.  That's interesting.

Comment: You cannot use CASE like this in SQLite.